# Why does XOR not produce the expected result

Tags: python, try-catch, google-colaboratory, difference, xor

```
3**2==9 ^ 3-2==4 

False

True ^ False

TRUE
```

Why is the result of first line False while it should be True?

Comment: Now just do the second part: read about operator precedence.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look into [How to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the operator ^ has more priority than == and the operation 9 ^ 3 has priority

Answer (score 0):

It returns `False` because of operation priority.

The priority of ^ is more than priority of ==

You can see the priority of operations in this [Link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity)